# How to Users of a specific Room and filter these users with specific spatie tag?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, tags

I have a User model that have spatie tags (developer and consultant).
I have a Room model that have many to many relation with User.
I want to return users of a specific room with tag of "consultant".
Can you please help me to do that?
I can find my specific room by id and also I can use relation to get its users but I dont know how to filter them by tag.
I hope you understand my point.
this is what I tried so far but didnt worked!

```
$room->users->withAnyTags('consultant');
```

here is my relation:

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,  'skyroom_room_user', 'skyroom_room_id', 'user_id')->with('tags');
}
```

if I run this:

```
$room->users;
```

it will return this:

```
{
    "id": "2c8fdf5a-fe94-4216-a3dc-8a49e76c6e34",
    "first_name": null,
    "last_name": null,
    "email": null,
    "slug": null,
    "username": "+989353785968",
    "gender": "male",
    "birthday": null,
    "national_code": null,
    "sheba": null,
    "country": null,
    "city": null,
    "bio": null,
    "long_bio": null,
    "education": null,
    "language": null,
    "type": "trainee",
    "avatar": null,
    "verified_at": null,
    "certified_at": null,
    "referred_by": null,
    "referred_at": null,
    "skyroom_user_id": 9379122,
    "skyroom_username": "09353785968",
    "skyroom_nickname": "مصطفی طاهری",
    "skyroom_access": 1,
    "created_at": "2021-04-08T13:22:42.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-04-08T13:22:42.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "tags": []
},
{
    "id": "33b1a31d-1aae-4c38-8c07-0793de5a4216",
    "first_name": "حامد",
    "last_name": "پوسانه",
    "email": "h.pousaneh@gmail.com",
    "slug": "hamed",
    "username": "+989127426900",
    "gender": "male",
    "birthday": "1990-05-28 19:37:12",
    "national_code": null,
    "sheba": null,
    "country": "Iran",
    "city": "Tehran",
    "bio": "مدیریت کسب و کار",
    "long_bio": "مدیریت کسب و کار از دانشگاه صنعتی امیرکبیر",
    "education": "کارشناسی ارشد",
    "language": "فارسی، آذری و انگلیسی",
    "type": "trainer",
    "avatar": null,
    "verified_at": null,
    "certified_at": null,
    "referred_by": "a9ca25bd-18fb-4271-8155-0a75d9dc31d9",
    "referred_at": null,
    "skyroom_user_id": 8025480,
    "skyroom_username": "09127426900",
    "skyroom_nickname": "حامد پوسانه",
    "skyroom_access": 3,
    "created_at": "2021-04-08T13:06:24.000000Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-04-08T15:07:13.000000Z",
    "deleted_at": null,
    "tags": [
        {
            "id": "71de78b1-15ad-410d-9778-50cb9b3bd4ca",
            "name": {
                "en": "consultant"
            },
            "slug": {
                "en": "consultant"
            },
            "type": "user-system-tag",
            "order_column": 3,
            "created_at": "2021-04-08T13:06:24.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2021-04-08T13:06:24.000000Z",
            "pivot": {
                "taggable_id": "33b1a31d-1aae-4c38-8c07-0793de5a4216",
                "tag_id": "71de78b1-15ad-410d-9778-50cb9b3bd4ca",
                "taggable_type": "App\\Models\\User"
            }
        },
```

Comment: can you try with  $room->users->withAnyTags(['consultant']);  .. and please tell me what

Comment: please tell whether this helped you..

Comment: @MidhunRaj tnx for your comment but it didnt help.    BadMethodCallException: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::withAnyTags does not exist. in file /var/www/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Macroable/Traits/Macroable.php on line 103

Comment: Did the below answer helped you ..$room->users()->withAnyTags('consultant')->get()..if so please accept that as answer..

Comment: @MidhunRaj noit didnt. it returns null. but I checked my database and I know it should not be null

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have created your relationships correctly, the syntax for retrieving tagged models would be:

```
$room->users()->withAnyTags('consultant')->get()
```

If you wanted to search for multiple tags, you would provide an array to `withAnyTags`:

```
$room->users()->withAnyTags(['consultant', 'developer'])->get()
```

Comment: tnxfor your reply. I did try this and it returns null. I am sure about my relation and also about tag. I will add relation to my question.

Comment: If the result is `null`, you will need to check your relationships are correct and that you have any `Users` associated to `$room` with the tag `consultant`.

Comment: please check the question again.I updated it

Comment: Can you update your question with exactly how you're trying to get users or a room with a tag.